# Passing parameters using Window.location.href

Tags: php, html, href, window.location

hope you fine and well,

how i can pass more than one parameter using window.location.href

i have the following code:

```
    $id = $scope.x.id ;
    $Name=$scope.x.Name;
    $window.location.href = '/myfiles/test.php?id=' + $id ;
```

i can pass the variable id and receive it successfully in test.php page, but how i can pass Name also ?! what is the right syntax ?!

regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$id = $scope.x.id ;
$Name=$scope.x.Name;
$window.location.href = '/myfiles/test.php?id=' . $id . '&Name=' . $Name;
```

But you should look at POST method instead. It's safer and looks better (no clutter in the adress field)

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: thank you but didn't work for sorry, how i can POST in my case ?!

Comment: What happened when you tried it? Are you sure the code on test.php is correct  for receiving? ||||||| POST:That requires more code from you. I can't give you a golden answer if I don't know anything about the rest of the page.

Comment: thank you dear, it worked now , i just replaced the dots by + 
test.php?id='  + $id  + '&Name='  + $Name ;

Comment: Ok. +? Don't know why it doesn't work with dot. But again, look at POST. It's not hard to switch but it will look so much better